# SKPaymentQueue addTransactionObserver issue when it is added after Amazons TransferManager and a BFTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, in-app-purchase, aws-sdk

I pretty much follow Ray Wenderlich's example for doing In-App purchases.  This includes that I get my product information first from a server.  In my case I use Amazon Web Services.

The problem I have is that `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` is not working, which means that `- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions` is not being called.

`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` gets called within the `_productIDCompletionHandler` block.

I have narrowed it down to the following code.  As long as I call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` before continueWithExecutor the observer works.  If I call the addTransactionObserver within the BFTask block or after, then updatedTransactions method is not being called.

```
-(void)getProductidsWithCompletionHandler:(AWSAccessProductIDsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

_productIDCompletionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

// Construct the NSURL for the download location.
NSString *downloadingFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"aws_downloadedproductidfile"];
NSURL *downloadingFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:downloadingFilePath];

// Construct the download request.
AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest *downloadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new];

downloadRequest.bucket = [self bucketStringForType:WB_com_test];
downloadRequest.key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",COM_PRODUCTIDS_FILEPATH,COM_PRODUCTIDS_FILENAME];
downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = downloadingFileURL;

[[transferManager download:downloadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                       withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                                                           if (task.error){
                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                               _productIDCompletionHandler(NO,nil);
                                                               _productIDCompletionHandler = nil;
                                                           }

                                                           if (task.result) {
                                                               NSLog(@"Success: ");

                                                               AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadOutput *output = task.result;
                                                               NSURL *url = (NSURL *)output.body;
                                                               NSArray *products = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];
                                                               DDLogVerbose(@"Success Result Count: %lu", (unsigned long)[products count]);

                                                               if (products)
                                                               {
                                                                   _productIDCompletionHandler( YES, products);
                                                               } else
                                                               {
                                                                   _productIDCompletionHandler( NO, nil);
                                                               }
                                                               _productIDCompletionHandler = nil;
                                                           }
                                                           return nil;
                                                       }];
```

}

When the above _productIDCompletionHandler handler returns it is on the main thread so this is not the problem, but somehow the thread is "dirty".

**Edit More Information added**

My in-app purchase class calls my AWS class to get a file which contains all my products. I need to build up my product list from what is stored on AWS before I let Apples observer start. The strange thing is as I pointed out above, if I set the observer before calling getProductidsWithCompletionHandler then it works. Where it currently is, nothing happens.

```
if (!awsAccess) {
awsAccess = [AWSAccess new];
}

[awsAccess getProductidsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *awsProductIDs) {

if (success)
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"Got ProductIDs from AWS...");
    for (NSDictionary *productInfoDict in awsProductIDs)
    {
        IAPProductInfo *info =[[IAPProductInfo alloc] initFromDict:productInfoDict];
        [self addInfo:info forProductIdentifier:info.productIdentifier];
    }

    DDLogVerbose(@"Adding the Apple transaction observer in case there are old purchases.");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];


} else {
    DDLogVerbose(@"Error getting ProductIDs from AWS...");

}
}];
```

The in-app purchase class which contains the above code and the observer is called from the Appdelegate as well as when a user initiates a purchase through the app but there is always ever only one observer as my in-app purchase class is a singleton.

**Update 2 based on comments**

TestIApurchase.h implements the SKPaymentTransactionObserver delegate.  I have created a new test class with only 3 functions.  This class is used exclusively in the app delegate.

I have put comments where I have tried the observer and whether it worked or not.

I have checked "self" and it is not nil.  I have also checked that the observer is called on the main no.1 thread and it is, which is what BFExecutor is in the AWS code for.

```
#import "TestIAPurchase.h"
#import "AWSAccess.h"

@implementation TestIAPurchase


-(void)checkForFailedPurchases {
DDLogVerbose(@"checking for failed purchases by getting all products and waiting to see if Apple replies.");

//Tried it here and it works immediately
//[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

[self loadProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    DDLogVerbose(@"checking for failed purchases Request for products has returned from AWS...");

    if (!success) {
        DDLogVerbose(@"checking for failed purchases Request For Products Failed");

    } else
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"checking for failed purchases Request For Products was a success...");
        //Tried it here and it does not work if I go and get the AWS information
        //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    }
}];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
 DDLogVerbose(@"paymentQueue - updatedTransaction...");
for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState)
    {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            DDLogVerbose(@"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            DDLogVerbose(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            DDLogVerbose(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:
            DDLogVerbose(@"SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred");
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            DDLogVerbose(@"SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
};

}


- (void)loadProductsWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError * error))productCompletionHandler
{
 DDLogVerbose(@"loadProductsWithCompletionHandler - by getting them from AWS.");


AWSAccess * awsAccess = [AWSAccess new];

//Tried it here and it works immediately
//[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

[awsAccess getProductidsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *awsProductIDs) {


    if (success)
    {
        DDLogVerbose(@"Adding the Apple transaction observer in case there are old purchases.");
        //Trying it here and it does not work
        //[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

        if (productCompletionHandler) {
            productCompletionHandler(TRUE, nil);
        }

    } else {
        DDLogVerbose(@"Error getting ProductIDs from AWS...");
        if (productCompletionHandler) {
            productCompletionHandler(FALSE, nil);
        }
    }
 }];
}
@end
```

Comment: According to the API doc, "Your application should add an observer to the payment queue during application initialization." You do not seem to be calling `- addTransactionObserver:` during application initialization. Also, sharing the implementation of `completionHandler` and how you are calling `- getProductidsWithCompletionHandler:` may help.

Comment: Sure no problem.  yes the observer is added when the app is initialised, but as I am trying to explain, I first need to get from AWS my file which contains the products I am currently offering.  I have shared the further code for you.

Comment: So you are certain you are calling `addTransactionObserver` on the main thread and that `self` is not nil, and yet you do not see delegate callbacks when you try to make a purchase? That is very odd indeed. What if you try starting a purchase immediately after adding the observer, just for debugging?

Comment: Based on the updated code snippet, `- addTransactionObserver:` is not called during the application initialization because the block is asynchronously dispatched. You may need to refactor the in-app purchase implementation and remove the dependency of the item list from the `- addTransactionObserver:` call.

Comment: I have added new code. To remove as many issues as possible I have made a test class exclusively with the problem. @ Yosuke the addTransactionObserver should also be able to be called asynchronously and is a well recognised way of doing it. I need to get my product information first before Apple tells me what ID was purchased. @Ben Yes - main thread - yes self is not nil.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's just recommended ("should") that you add your transaction observer on app init. You definitely can do it later and still have it work. If I had to guess, Apple's emphasis is that you start observing soon after launch in case the user is waiting for goods that have been paid for but weren't previously delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem.  It has nothing to do with AWS, it was just by chance that AWS was tied up with my testing.

Basically as I was using the above code in the app delegate, Facebook's code was also being started in the app delegate with `[FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];`.  Facebook listens to the same observer too.  If I used the AWS code this was going Facebook enough time to become an observer and receive a response from apple.  Then I was registering also as an observer and not getting a response from Apple which I assume is because Apple had only just sent one.